# Substring Error in C++

Tags: c++, substring

I am writing a program that will calculate password strength according to two formulas. It requires the user to enter 2 passwords, one being eight characters or less and the other being 20 characters or more. The first parts executes with out problem. But, when I go to execute the second part, it works but the substring function that extracts the next twelve characters keeps extracting 18 characters.  I have looked over my code several times and do not understand why it is doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//All variables and constants are declared
string eight_password, first_char, next_seven, twenty_password, first_char_twenty, next_seven_twenty, next_twelve, remaining;
int ep_length, character_set, first_char_length, next_seven_length, character_set_20, twenty_length, first_char_twenty_length, next_seven_twenty_length, next_twelve_length, remaining_length;
double eight_ent_strength, eight_nist_strength, twenty_ent_strength, twenty_nist_strength;
const int NIST_FIRST = 4, NIST_SEVEN = 2, NIST_REM = 1, NIST_CHARACTER=94, NIST_BONUS=6;
const double NIST_TWELVE = 1.5; 
//Console prompts for user to input password and character set
cout << "Hello! Please enter a password of 8 characters or less (including spaces!):" << endl;
getline(cin, eight_password);
cout << "What character set is being used?";
cin >> character_set;
cout << endl;
//Password length and information entropy strength are calculated and saved to the appropriate variables
ep_length = eight_password.length();
eight_ent_strength = (ep_length*((log(character_set))/(log(2))));
//First character and next seven characters are extracted and saved to the appropriate variables
first_char = eight_password.substr(0, 1);
next_seven = eight_password.substr(1, 7);
//First character and next seven characters lengths are calculated and saved to the appropriate variables
first_char_length = first_char.length();
next_seven_length = next_seven.length();
//NIST strength is calculated and saved to the appropriate variable
eight_nist_strength = (first_char_length*NIST_FIRST) + (next_seven_length*NIST_SEVEN)+((character_set/NIST_CHARACTER)*NIST_BONUS);

//The information that was calculated is now printed back out on the console to be viewed by the user
cout << "Your password " << eight_password << " is " << ep_length << " characters long. According to the information " << endl;
cout<<"entropy formula, it has a strength of " << eight_ent_strength << "." << endl;
cout << "The first character is \"" << first_char << "\" and the next seven characters are \"" << next_seven << "\". " << endl;
cout << "According to the NIST formula, it has a strength of " << eight_nist_strength << "." << endl << endl;

cin.ignore();

cout << "Now, please enter a password of 20 characters (including spaces!):" << endl;
getline(cin, twenty_password);
cout << "What character set is being used?";
cin >> character_set_20;
cout << endl;

twenty_length = twenty_password.length();

twenty_ent_strength = (twenty_length*((log(character_set_20)) / (log(2))));

first_char_twenty = twenty_password.substr(0, 1);
next_seven_twenty = twenty_password.substr(1, 7);
next_twelve = twenty_password.substr(8, 19);
remaining = twenty_password.substr(19);

first_char_twenty_length = first_char_twenty.length();
next_seven_twenty_length = next_seven_twenty.length();
next_twelve_length = next_twelve.length();
remaining_length = remaining.length();

twenty_nist_strength = (first_char_twenty_length*NIST_FIRST) + (next_seven_twenty_length*NIST_SEVEN) + (next_twelve_length*NIST_TWELVE) + (remaining_length*NIST_REM) + ((character_set_20 / NIST_CHARACTER)*NIST_BONUS);

cout << "Your password " << twenty_password << " has a length of " << twenty_length << "." << endl;
cout << "According to the information entropy formula, it has a strength of " << twenty_ent_strength << endl;
cout << "The first character is \"" << first_char_twenty << "\"." << endl;
cout<< "The next seven characters are \"" << next_seven_twenty <<"\"."<< endl;
cout << "The next twelve characters are \"" << next_twelve << "\"." << endl;
cout<< "The remaining characters are \"" << remaining << "\"." << endl;
cout << "According to the NIST formula, it has a strength of " << twenty_nist_strength <<"." << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps start by writing code that's actually legible. Then, _narrow down your problem_ by constructing a [testcase](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0):

`next_twelve = twenty_password.substr(8, 19);` will extract 19 chars

`next_twelve = twenty_password.substr(8, 12);` will extract 12 chars

First parameters is start position. Second parameter is length.

```
string substr (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos) const;
```

Comment: But why is that? I only want it to extract 12 chars.

Comment: coz `next_seven = eight_password.substr(1, 7);` extracts 7 chars